# What is the difference between usage of “y” and “là”?

Tags: usage, indications-de-lieu

Consider the following context:
*Un grand magasin est situé en ville.* What would be a better continuation and why?

> On peut y acheter des meubles.

or

> Là, on peut acheter des meubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first continuation is definitely the best. The use of *là* is more or less reserved to oral language to refer to the current location of the speaker or a location he can point to. According to the TLF, [*là*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A0):

> Adverbe de lieu (plus rarement de temps) marquant le lieu où se trouve le locuteur ou un lieu plus ou moins éloigné de lui.
>
> [Accompagné d'un geste ou déterminé précédemment dans le discours] Dans tel lieu (autre que celui où se trouve le locuteur, désigné par lui et plus ou moins éloigné de lui).

*Là* may also combine with complements *là-bas* (this one means “slightly far away”), *là-haut*, *là-devant*, *là-derrière*…

In some formulations like *être là* ou *jusque-là*, the word *là* has a figurative or temporal value. Also *“Là où [j'étais]”* is used for “the place where [I was]”. This common in written language as well.
But to refer to a previously mentioned location (as opposed to an abstract or a new specific location you designate), whenever the pronoun *y* can be used, use it instead of the demonstrative adverb *là*.