# COD and COI pronouns in infinitive clauses

Tags: pronoms, infinitif, pronoms-personnels, compléments

As practice, I'm writing my tasks list on French. So far I have:

1. *trouver une place pour sauvegarde les fichiers.*
2. *rétrécir les.* (is this usage of COD correct?)
3. (here I'm trying to write "move them there" — usage of both COD and COI together) I think maybe: *déplacer les lui.*

Is this correct?

Comment: I think your problem lies in where to place personnel pronouns. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.connectigramme.com/tableaux-pronoms.htm/odyframe.htm) and come back with a more precise question if necessary. 1) is correct. 2) *les* is COD so it comes before the verb. 3) Imperative sentence so COD pronoun after the verb. Don't understand your use of "lui". There ? Not a personal pronoun, could use adverbs "ici" ou "là", not personal pronoun "lui" in any case.

Comment: I understand. Why didn't you included it as an answer, I will accept it if you do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first item is almost correct. You need a definite article article though:

> Trouver une place pour la sauvegarde des fichiers.

In the second item *les* is the appropriate pronoun, but it should come before the verb:

> Les rétrécir.

The same applies to the last item. Also you need *y* (not *lui*) to specify a place.

> Les y déplacer.

Comment: Using lá, like Laure said in the comment above is also correct? "Les déplacer lá" ?

Comment: With *là* it's unclear that it refers to the place from item 1. Have a look here: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/what-is-the-difference-between-usage-of-y-and-la

Comment: It's perfectly clear to me since there is no other places involved. Common sense (AKA information not in the text) is allowed to supersede overly analytical logic, and does so constantly.

Comment: @Tom: Of course you could use *là*. *Y* could only be used if the place the pronoun *y* represents has been defined before. But the way you present your sentences they can only be dealt with as unconnected sentences. That's why I suggested you came back with a more precise question.

Comment: @Circeus, Laure: the question is perfectly clear, the pronoun refers to « la place » from item 1. I would not understand if a native francophone I know used *là* to refer to this previously mentioned place. I would ask them what they meant.

Answer (score 2):

1. The first one is not correct. It should be:

   - trouver une place pour **sauvegarder** les fichiers.(I would even say "Trouver **de la** place pour sauvegarder les fichiers)
     or
   - trouver une place pour **la** sauvegarde **des** fichiers.
2. Direct-object pronouns (le, la, les, me, te, vous, nous) always come before verbs. So it's gonna be:

   - les rétrécir (it's better to say "rétrécir leur taille" or "réduire leur taille")
3. The last part will be:

   - les y déplacer.

Answer (score 1):

D'un sens purement informatique "retrecir un fichier" ne veut rien dire.
Soit l'on "compresse un fichier" (if you use winzip for example), soit l'on "tronque un fichier" dans le cas ou on lui ote une partie de son contenu.